# Sorting using objects in vector

Tags: c++, templates, sorting, stdvector

I would like to modify the following code so that I can sort using objects.
The current code is fine when sorting individual methods that return a single value.
How can I implement using methods that returns a object;

```
template<typename T, typename M, template<typename> class C = std::less>
struct method_comparer : std::binary_function<T, T, bool>
{
explicit method_comparer(M (T::*p)() const) : p_(p) { }

bool operator ()(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) const
{
return C<M>()((lhs.*p_)(), (rhs.*p_)());
}

private:
M (T::*p_)() const;
};



template<typename T, typename M>
method_comparer<T, M> make_method_comparer(M (T::*p)() const)
{
return method_comparer<T, M>(p);
}

template<template<typename> class C, typename T, typename M>
method_comparer<T, M, C> make_method_comparer2(M (T::*p)() const)
{
 return method_comparer<T, M, C>(p);
 }
```

Main.cpp

```
// works well
std::sort(vec_p2d.begin(),vec_p2d.end(),make_method_comparer(&Point2D::getX));
```

// Would like to implement this

```
 std::sort(vec_l2d.begin(),vec_l2d.end(),make_method_comparer(&Line2D::getPt1));
```

getPt1() methods return a Point2D object which contains the values for int x and int y;

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just implement a small one-line `operator<` for your classes?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am sorting using 4 different citiera on 4 different class that y i am using a template. To make generic.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Or can i just implement a different function just to compare objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICS, you can leave your code as is. The only thing you must define is a comparison operator for `Point2D` or whatever object you're returning:

```
class Point2D {
public:
    friend bool operator<(const Point2D &p1, const Point2D &p2) { ...; }
    ...
};
```

You can also remove your `method_comparer` class and just give appropriate comparer functions to sort:

```
bool compare_line_points(const Line2D &l1, const Line2D &l2) {
    return l1.getPt1() < l2.getPt1();
}
```

and

```
std::sort(vec_l2d.begin(), vec_l2d.end(), compare_line_points);
```

Depending on your requirements, these are just a bunch of one- or two-liners. No need for templates.

Answer (score 1):

If you may use boost, how about:

`std::sort(vec_p2d.begin(), vec_p2d.end(), boost::bind( &Point2D::getX, _1 ) < boost::bind( &Point2D::getX, _2 ) );`

&

`std::sort(vec_p2d.begin(), vec_p2d.end(), boost::bind( &Point2D::getPt1, _1 ) < boost::bind( &Point2D::getPt1, _2 ) );`?

Comment: i cant use boost. The reason i use template, I have 4 classess that needs to sort using different citeria.

Comment: @user1571494 If you are using a C++11 enabled compiler, you could use `std::bind` instead?